# Google plus: How to get feedback after sharing my content?

Tags: redirect, share, google-plus

I am using share link for Google plus as follows:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}"      
onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

After user clicks on the confirm button "Share", in google popup window, my website has no feedback whether user really shared content or canceled sharing (he clicked on cancel button).
Is it possible to get feedback from popup window?

The another option, how to use share link is without poopup window:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOUR_URL_HERE
```

But my website cannot get feedback from this way, either. Although the google plus form redirects user back to my website, it doesn't send any information nor in POST nor in GET array.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the Web Share Button as described in the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/). If you use this method, you can add the optional `data-onendinteraction` tag to the HTML to trigger a JavaScript callback, which you can use to track success / failure of the share.

Comment: There is no way to track the success or failure of the share. onendinteraction gives you only two params, the id and the event witch, as I notices is everytime "hover"